# Django Rest Framework - define required fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**EDIT**

I just want to raise exception when I do `BrokerSerializer(user).data` and any of values is `None`

I'm using DRF to serialize objects to export them through API, I don't use it to creating objects.

Looking for a simplest way to make fields required when serializing model.

The API needs some fields to be not null so I want to raise `APIMissingDataException` if any of them is null/None.

I tried:

```
class BrokerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    import_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk')
    deleted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    full_name = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.get_display_name')
    phone_work = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.contact_information.telephone')
    email_work = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.contact_information.email')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['import_id', 'deleted', 'full_name', 'phone_work', 'email_work']
    required_fields = fields


def validate(self, attrs):
    super().validate(attrs)
    if not all([attrs.get(fieldname) for fieldname in self.Meta.required_fields]):
        raise APIMissingDataException()
    return attrs

def get_deleted(self, obj):
    return 0
```

But `validate` function is not being called for some reason. I don't want to explicitely defining all fields just to add `required=False` parameters to them.

```
In [10]: b = BrokerSerializer(User.objects.first())                                                                                                                                                  

In [11]: b.data                                                                                                                                                                                       

# It should have raised exception since there are None
Out[11]: {'import_id': 1, 'deleted': 0, 'full_name': None, 'phone_work': None, 'email_work': None}

In [12]: b = BrokerSerializer(data=User.objects.first())                                                                                                                                             

In [13]: b.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[13]: False

In [14]: b.data                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[14]: {}
```

Is there a more comfortable way?

Comment: Do you return `attrs` from your `validate` method? Could you share more code of your serializer class and `User` model

Comment: No I don't but the `validate` method is not even being called. I thought that it is called automatically when serializing a model. There is nothing more. Suppose that user model contains those fields or there are methods in serializer which extracts them.

Comment: Are you calling `is_valid()` method of your serializer?

Comment: show us the code snippet that calls the serializer and/or the view+request you did

Comment: @Linovia I've added it at the bottom of the question. Just calling it through shell

Comment: Please add your serializer errors: I mean `b.errors` in you case.

Comment: I don't want to serialize dicts so b.is_valid doesn't make sense. b.errors returns message that dict was expected.

Answer (score 1):

DRF has builtin methods to handle it.

```
name = serializers.CharField(label="name field",required=True, allow_blank=False, allow_null=False)
```

Then use `serializer.is_valid()` to validate the data.

For more details, refer to [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/).

Comment: No it doesn't work. There are required=True which returns None.

Comment: required=True is for deserialization as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486876/8283848) is also applicable here :)
**Summary**
The validation process undergoes ***only while `Deserialization` process*** (input is a **`dict`** like object) and you are trying a ***`Serialization` process***. In the case of **`Serialization`**, DRF assumes the given object is a valid one and hence it doesn't require validation.