# DRF - Raise Exception if any defined field is None

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need to serialize model to `JSON`. Then send this `JSON` to one `API`.

But this `API` requires some fields to be not `None`.

I have a list of these fields. In this case, let's say it's just `['telephone']` but it can be much more.

For example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    telephone = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.telephone')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','telephone']
```

Serialization:

```
>>> UserSerializer(user).data
>>> {'first_name':'Michael','last_name':'Jackson','telephone':None}
```

Since `API` requires some fields like `telephone`, I want `UserSerializer` to `raise ValidationError` when the required field is `None`.

So in this case I couldn't serialize `user` because `telephone` is `None`.

I tried many things including adding `required=True` to the `telephone` but nothing works.

Is there a way to `validate` serialized data? Note that I'm not talking about `deserialization`.

Comment: why you try the `required=False` instead `required=True`?

Comment: It was a mistype. Of course I tried required=True :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why validation not working?

The validation process undergoes ***only while `Deserialization` process*** (input is a **`dict`** like object) and you are trying a ***`Serialization` process***. In the case of **`Serialization`**, DRF assumes the given object is a valid one and hence it doesn't require a validation.
**Source [DRF-serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers)**

---

### How can we make this happen?

**Method-1**
Make your user object to a user_data (`dict` object) and pass it to the serializer and run the validation.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
dict_user_data = {"first_name": user.first_name, "last_name": user.last_name, "telephone": user.userprofile.telephone}
user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=dict_user_data)
user_serializer.is_valid(True)
user_serializer.data
```

**Method-2**
Override the **`to_representation()`** method

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    telephone = serializers.CharField(source='userprofile.telephone')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'telephone']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        for field, value in data.items():
            if value is None:
                raise SomeExceptionHere({field: "can't be None"})
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. DRF serializers can do that right out the box. If a field is setted to be `null=False` or `required=True`, just do this.

```
data = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
data.is_valid(raise_exception=True
```

And that is it. A 400 error will be raised.

If you want, you can tweak the error message:

```
data = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
try:
    data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
except ValidationError as e:
   return HttpResponse(status_code=400, content=e)
```

Comment: Thanks but what is `user_data`. I want to serialize model.

Comment: Moreover I can't use required=True to any of readonly fields like `SerializerMethodField`

Comment: So you will need to use `serializers.ModelSerializer`, not `MethodSerializer`.

Comment: `user_data` is just any generic dict with the information you will use to create the model instance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not to validate data for de-serialization, but to validate for serialization. Expressions like **required=True** are all used to validate data for de-serialization. Serialization is handled in **to_representation** method of **Serializer** class (which is the base for **ModelSerializer**)

What you can do is, override **to_representation**, and have the method raise an exception if a required field value is None.

You may need to further subclass default DRF classes like **Field** (for a serializer field) and use your custom classes to be able to provide your functionality in a systematic manner. You do not want to rely on **required=True** for this, because it is used for another purpose already (for de-serialization validation).

What I suggest is, subclass **Field** class, add a property like "**required_for_read**", and define your serializer field with this property, using your custom field class. Then, in your overridden **to_representation** method, look for this property, and raise an exception if the field has this property as **True** but its value is **None**