# Django REST Framework (DRF): ModelSerializer does not validate models on serialization

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to ask how to use Django REST Framework (DRF) ModelSerializers correctly for serializing from model.

I have Django model with two required fields:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    desc = models.CharField()
```

I have DRF ModelSerializer:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'desc']
```

I can deseralize and validate incoming request using:

```
serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

But how to serialize and send response? DRF allows me to break contact built using ModelSerializer. If I forgot to set one of mandatory Book fields, it will still still pass through BookSerializer!

```
invalid_book = Book(title="Foo")    # but forgotten to set "desc"
serializer = BookSerializer(instance=invalid_book)
serializer.data        # it contains book without required "desc"
```

Serialized created using instance parameter throws error if I try `is_validate()`.

Why ModelSerializer can validate incoming data, but cannot outgoing?

Comment: The invalid data in database is saved when your validator did not catch them when they were being saved. So you should work on that so that no invalid data is saved in you database. BTW what do you want to do when data is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Validation is only performed when deserializing. As per the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializers):

> Serializers also provide deserialization, allowing parsed data to be converted back into complex types, after first validating the incoming data.

That makes sense (**edit**: in the way Django Rest Framework seems to be construed). Because it isn't the 'role' of the Serializer to make sure that your complex data such as querysets and model instances (eg. your `Book` instance) that you are going to serialize is construed 'legitimately', thus they also don't validate while serializing.

So if you would save the instance like `invalid_book.save()`, Django would throw an error because of the missing field.

**Edit**

After a comment about being 'a point of view' and thus being opiniated I want to stress and make clear that this seems to be the way that Django Rest Framework (DRF) is construed. After digging deeper on SO I link [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479141/drf-raise-exception-if-any-defined-field-is-none/55486876#55486876) in support.

Also if you read the documentation of DRF, it is somewhat implied that [serialization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) and [validation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) are two separate concepts.

Furthermore, [analyzing](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/4137ef41efa77bd404bdc078159081740abdf930/rest_framework/serializers.py#L211) `serializers.py` makes clear that validation is only run when calling `is_valid()` and the validation is only run on the provided `data` flag. In fact, it can't even be run when only an instance is provided:

```
def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
    self.instance = instance
    if data is not empty:
        self.initial_data = data
    self.partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    self._context = kwargs.pop('context', {})
    kwargs.pop('many', None)
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

...

def is_valid(self, raise_exception=False):
    assert hasattr(self, 'initial_data'), (
        'Cannot call `.is_valid()` as no `data=` keyword argument was '
        'passed when instantiating the serializer instance.'
    )

    if not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
        try:
            self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
        except ValidationError as exc:
            self._validated_data = {}
            self._errors = exc.detail
        else:
            self._errors = {}

    if self._errors and raise_exception:
        raise ValidationError(self.errors)

    return not bool(self._errors)
```

Comment: I can't agree with this "point of view". Serializer is a contract that I offer to outer world. Something like a barrier assuring invalid data will not be accepted but also not come outside API.

Comment: So answer is "ModerSerialer can't validate on serialization, only on deserialization". Correct?

Comment: @LiborJelinek I've edited my answer to clarify any doubts about being a 'point of view' and even more substantiate the proclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

You are under a very wrong assumption. A serializer (not de-serializer) does one thing. Convert an Object to JSON. Here, you are creating an object Book(name='sad book'). This is just a regular Python Object. Django Serializers will attempt to serialize any Object that is passed to it.

What you might be wondering is the field is required in Model but why doesn't the serializer validate? Because of the way DRF handles serialization. I will show some excerpts from DRF Source code.

This is how the data property is calulated.

```
class BaseSerializer():
...
...
@property
def data(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'initial_data') and not hasattr(self, '_validated_data'):
        msg = (
            'When a serializer is passed a `data` keyword argument you '
            'must call `.is_valid()` before attempting to access the '
            'serialized `.data` representation.\n'
            'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
            'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
        )
        raise AssertionError(msg)


    if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
        if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            # THIS IS WHERE WE GO. THE to_representation() CAN BE FOUND IN THE IMPLEMENTATION
            # OF ModelSerializer() which inherits from this class BaseSerializer
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
        elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
            self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
        else:
            self._data = self.get_initial()
    return self._data
```

What happens in ModelSerializer.to_representation() ?

```
class ModelSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    ...
    ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
    """
    Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
    """
    ret = OrderedDict()
    fields = self._readable_fields

    for field in fields:
        try:
            attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
        except SkipField:
            continue

        # We skip `to_representation` for `None` values so that fields do
        # not have to explicitly deal with that case.
        #
        # For related fields with `use_pk_only_optimization` we need to
        # resolve the pk value.
        check_for_none = attribute.pk if isinstance(attribute, PKOnlyObject) else attribute
        if check_for_none is None:
            ret[field.field_name] = None
        else:
            ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

    return ret
```

As you can see, in this case the serializer only maps the fields from the Object being passed. So, there is no validation during serialization. For more info, check the source code of DRF. It's pretty easy if you use Pycharm Pro.